# Sound Pool - Not Loading File

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a sound to my sound pool

I've been stuck on this for over a week now, tried various methods of loading in via url etc, but nothing works. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

I get the error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/claps.wav from drawable resource ID.

I know the file is in the apk becuase I unziped the apk to find it under /res/raw/claps.wav.

```
SoundPool mySoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        int myAudioFile = context.getResourceId("raw.claps");
        try{
            mySoundPool.load(context.getActivity(),myAudioFile,1);
        } catch (Exception e){
            message = String.valueOf(e);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SoundPool mySoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    int myAudioFile = getResId("claps", R.raw.class);
    try{
        mySoundPool.load(context.getActivity(),myAudioFile,1);
    } catch (Exception e){
        message = String.valueOf(e);
    }

public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {
    Field field = null;
    int resId = 0;
    try {
        field = c.getField(variableName);
        try {
            resId = field.getInt(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resId;
}
```

Comment: It should work, make sure the getResId() parameters are correct.

Comment: Ok, claps is the name of my sound file and do I need to change R.raw.class to anything specific? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: That should be fine, could you double check to see if claps is in the R.class and it's under raw. or perhaps it's under a different class(inside R)?  You can find the R.class file in the gen folder.

Comment: Yes, its under raw   public static final class raw {
        public static final int claps=0x7f040000;

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what the issue could be, getResId() should return the int. the only thing you could try is renaming claps. clean the project and run again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; half of my sounds would load, and half would cause android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException.  The reason was that one of my resource files in eclipse was out of sync with the file system.  When I refreshed the file, the sounds all loaded from then on.